# How to fix the restricted drag and drop in design tab in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout-editor

I'm working with Android Studio 2.3.3. I'm trying to drag a View (like Button in Palette) and drop it in some places but Android Studio don't let me to place it where I want it just let to drop it in 9 places. How to fix it?

[image: Palette]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the underlying Layout of the View. Try Using `RelativeLayout` if you want free-form drag and drop